# Selecting another field in grouped rows by the maximum value of another field

Tags: sql

I need a little help with SQL. I want to get the value of the field Address from the table where CallsCount is maximum for each KeyCon group.

| Key | KeyCon | Adress | CallsCount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | Build9 | 15 |
| 2 | 100 | Build0 | 10 |
| 3 | 101 | Build7 | 24 |
| 4 | 101 | Build4 | 17 |
| 5 | 102 | Build3 | 10 |

At the output I want to get

| KeyCon | Adress |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | Build9 |
| 101 | Build7 |
| 102 | Build3 |

Comment: [SQL select only rows with max value on a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your DBMS supports it, you could use the `row_number` function.

```
select keyCon, address
from (
  select keyCon, address, 
    row_number() over (partition by keyCon order by callsCount desc) as rn
  from my_table
  )z
where rn = 1;
```

| keyCon | address |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | Build9 |
| 101 | Build7 |
| 102 | Build3 |

---

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
create table test ([Key] int,   KeyCon int, Adress varchar(30), CallsCount int);
insert into test values(1,  100,'Build9',   15);
insert into test values(2,  100,'Build0',   10);
insert into test values(3,  101,'Build7',   24);
insert into test values(4,  101,'Build4',   17);
insert into test values(5,  102,'Build3',   10);
insert into test values(6,  102,'Build3-2', 10);
select * from
  (select KeyCon,max(callscount) maxqty
   from test
   group by KeyCon
  ) g
inner join test t on t.keycon=g.keycon and callscount=maxqty
order by g.keycon
```

I'll add 1 row to your test data, where 2 rows have equal CallsCount. Both lines will be included in the result.

| KeyCon | maxqty | Key | KeyCon | Adress | CallsCount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 15 | 1 | 100 | Build9 | 15 |
| 101 | 24 | 3 | 101 | Build7 | 24 |
| 102 | 10 | 5 | 102 | Build3 | 10 |
| 102 | 10 | 6 | 102 | Build3-2 | 10 |